# Clang boost header not found

Tags: boost, clang

I am trying to compile a Python PCL module which builds some C++ source. I am getting this error:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'pcl/_pcl.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pcl._pcl' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/HEAD/include/pcl-1.8 -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.3/include/eigen3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/HEAD/include/pcl-1.8 -I/usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.8.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcl/HEAD/include/pcl-1.8 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pcl/_pcl.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/pcl/_pcl.o
pcl/_pcl.cpp:244:10: fatal error: 'boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp' file not
      found
#include "boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang'
```

For whatever reason clang isn't looking in `/usr/local/include` where it most definitely would find the boost headers. As you can see it is linking all the other dependencies fine. What can I add that so clang will find boost?

On OSX 10.10, nothing fancy happening anywhere. Boost was probably installed by homebrew, but the files are all in `/usr/local/include/boost` as I'd expect.

Comment: What OS, environment, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of `/usr/bin/clang++ -v some_test_file.cpp` but chances are `/usr/local/include` isn't in the standard search path of the compiler.

You'll need to add `-I/usr/local/include` to `CXXFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` or whatever appropriate place in your build script or environment. It seems the python build script is failing to properly detect Boost.

If the above is not true (and `/usr/local/include` does show up in the output), make sure `/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp` exists.

Comment: it turns out every time i install a new Xcode beta it removes command line tools, a quick `xcode-select --install` fixed the search path issues.